# jQuery. jParallax. How I can change default values on click?

Tags: jquery, parallax

I have this -
`$('.parallax').jparallax({mouseResponse:true}, {}, {});`

And I need change mouseResponse to false after click on the link -

```
$('a.goto').click(function(){ 
});
```

hepl me please (

upd:

I use this plugin to scroll big div`s in small one. And I want to stop this plugin (stop any scroll) after click on the link below.

f. ex.

html:

> ```
> <div id="content" class="parallax">
> <div style="width:3466px; height:1233px;">img src="../7.jpg"/></div>
> </div>
> <a href="#j" class="stop"> stopScrolling </a>
> ```

js:

i try:

```
$('a.stop').click(function(){
$('.parallax').jparallax({mouseResponse:false}, {}, {}); 
});

$('.parallax').jparallax({mouseResponse:true}, {}, {});
```

and

```
$('a.stop').click(function(){
jQuery.fn.jparallax.mouseResponse({mouseResponse:false});
});

$('.parallax').jparallax({mouseResponse:true}, {}, {});
```

upd2:

I found this http://flickaway.s3.amazonaws.com/ploreex/ploreex.html
- They Lock jparallax on press space. Don`t know how to do it in my project

Comment: Never heard about that plugin, very crazy stuff! http://webdev.stephband.info/parallax.html

Comment: Mind expanding on what the links are and what you're trying to accomplish? Are you trying to prevent links from redirecting to another page or what? Some markup code would be nice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solution:

```
var varName = false;
```

find in plugin code - // Mouse Response - and replace with your var

```
// Mouse Response
    if (settings.mouseResponse) {
        jQuery().mousemove(function(mouse){

            if (varName) return;
```

change var on click

```
    $('a').click(function(){

    stopParallax = true;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`$("a.goto").click();` I don't know if that is what you want

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're thinking this :

```
$('a.goto').click(function(ev){ 
ev.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're trying to accomplish? http://webdev.stephband.info/parallax_demos_type.html

the source code is pretty straight forward with one tweak I made for better practice jQuery event bubbling

```
$('a.goto').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var ref = $(this).attr("href");
    $('#parallax').trigger("jparallax", [ref]);
});
```

Assuming a markup like so

```
<a href="#anchor" class="goto">Anchor</a>
```

Comment: this function scroll to anchor. I want to stop any scroll on click on the link, but I don`t know how update mouseResponse